# Connecting django to MS SQL Server using odbc

Tags: sql-server, django, odbc

I'm getting an error when trying to execute manage.py runserver. I've installed django-pyodbc and the odbc driver 17 for sql server. Do I need to import pyodbc somewhere in the project? I am very new to django and python in general but I want to use ms sql server instead of sqlite. This is the code in manage.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',

        'OPTIONS': {'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
                    }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop>manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001770CD61438>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 305, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 203, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "C:\Users\Kirk\PycharmProjects\PyShop\venv\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.driver_charset = opts.get('driver_charset', None)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get
```

'

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: remove `OPTIONS` from db config. It doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Change your options to following. Error might be caused by string parsing function of pyodbc library.

```
'OPTIONS': {
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
}
```

or

```
‘OPTIONS’: {“ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server”, }
```

Comment: Yes I was missing the 'driver': Thank you!